# saving console output to a query in file

Tags: prolog

I use Swi-prolog for windows and want to save answer to a query in file. for a simple example,suppose:
the'input.pl' file has these predicates:

```
parent(a,b).
parent(c,d).
parent(e,f).
  answer :-
    open('output.txt',write, Stream),
    (  write(Stream,parent(a,b)),fail   %%%%%% how to ?
   ;true
    ),
   close(Stream).
```

So, with calling 'answer' query, i want to save  'yes' in output.txt file. 
How to I can do it?

Comment: I tried: `swipl -g "parent(a,b),writeln(yes),halt" -q parent.pl` and get `yes` on stdout, which I can pipe to a file.

Comment: @K.ROS, but I get  ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: swipl -s ... .

Comment: In this particular case, `listing(parent/2)` is the safest way.

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJZ5w.png)

click right on your prolog terminal(prolog output screen), then you can see save  as button. If you click the button, accomplish it. The output file save as txt.file